# How to display videos from a Sharepoint 2013 Asset Library

Tags: 2013, asset-library, video-richmedia

I am trying to display videos from an asset library in SharePoint page. I need it similar to Picture Library SlideShow. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Dheeraj

Comment: ootb slides are for images. For videos you need probably an additional webpart like https://resources.depaul.edu/sharepoint/webparts/photo-video-gallery/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: Yeah that is exactly which I need help in...

Comment: if you are using SP Enterprise you could use content search webpart as described in https://sdtimes.com/working-with-video-content-in-sharepoint-2013/